# Unable to get TOC section at the top of the page

Tags: mediawiki

Creating a mediawiki page, unable to get TOC section at the top of the page, its appearing at the middle of the page

[Please click here to view the page](http://www.dotweb.in/projects/india_futures/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Kindly help us out, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TOC [will be positioned](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTable_of_contents#Positioning_the_TOC) right before the first section heading (the first `h2` heading), unless you position it manually. You can put it anywhere in the page using the magic word `__TOC__` in the position where you want it to appear.

Comment: Thx Leo your instruction worked